# Python - Iterating through 2 list with arithmetic function

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have 2 python list, *stock_level* to track the amount of inventory and *required* to indicate the amount of each item in *stock_level* needed to create each product.

```
stock_level = [70, 20, 20 , 20] 
required = [20, 20, 20, 20]
```

How do I iterate through the 2 lists to find out how many products can be made and the inventory left outstanding after making the products i.e. given the above value, only 1 product can be made and *stock_level* should end up to be [50, 0, 0, 0]

EDIT:
The products can only be made if all the values in *stock_level* is greater than *required*. If,

```
stock_level = [20, 20, 20, 20]
required = [70, 20, 20, 20]
```

No products should have been made as the first element in *stock_level* is lesser than the first element in *required*. A product should only be made if the value in *stock_level* is greater than the corresponding element in *required*.

```
stock_level = [70, 20, 20, 20]
required = [20, 20, 20, 20]
```

In this example, only 1 product should be made as after the first run, *stock_level* will become [50, 0, 0, 0] and there won't be enough inventory in the 2nd to 4th element of *stock_level* to make another product.

I came up with something like this.

```
made = 0
for x in required:
    for y in stock_level:
        while True:
            if x > y:
                print("Insufficient")
                break
            else:
                # stock_leve minus required
                print("Product created")
            made += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is nesting the loop but you need to go through both list in parallel. Also you end up with an infinite loop.

While zipping the array is the best option, find here an adjusted version using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), it should help you understand.

**Not managed the case where there is insufficient stock.**

```
stock_level = [70, 20, 20 , 20] 
required = [20, 20, 20, 20]

for i, x in enumerate(required):
    y = stock_level[i]
    if x > y:
        print("Insufficient")
    else:
        # stock_leve minus required
        print("Product created")
        made = y - x
        stock_level[i] = made

stock_level #=> [50, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

Updating after the edit, if I got the point.
The problem is still the nested loop and the logic itself used.

**To understand the following implementation, please, dig into the doc:**

- [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)
- [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

Here is a possible implementation:

```
stock_level = [70, 40, 40, 50] 
required = [20, 20, 20, 20]

tmp = zip(stock_level, required)
tmp = list(zip(stock_level, required))
makeable = 0

while True:
    update_make = tmp
    tmp = [ [stk - req, req] for stk, req in tmp ]
    can_be_made = all([stk >= 0 for stk, _ in tmp])
    if can_be_made:
        makeable += 1
    else:
        break
        
print(makeable) #=> 2
print(update_make) #=> [[30, 20], [0, 20], [0, 20], [10, 20]]
actual_stock_level = [stk for stk, req in update_make]
print(actual_stock_level) #=> [30, 0, 0, 10]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. The code that you've provided works, however, I was wondering if there is anyway to track how many products have been made i.e. how many times it went into the else part of the code.

Comment: Apologies for the poor explanation. I have since added to the edit. The whole point is that in order for the product to be made, it will require inventory from the 1st to 4th element of stock_level and at any point in time should the values in stock_level fall below the corresponding value in required, no products should be made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip()` to iterate over the two lists together. something like `[max(a-b,0) for a,b in zip(l1, l2)]`

Comment: Forgive me but I'm a little new to python. Could you provide me with a little more explanation and is there a way to track how many products have been created? Thanks!

Comment: please upvote and accept if this answers your question. I'd be happy to follow up with an explanation...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Creating a new list for the item added is a great idea so that we can reduce the number of steps to achieve this.

```
stock_level = [70, 2, 20 , 20] 
required = [20, 20, 20, 20]
new_stock_level = []

for i, x in enumerate(required):
    y = stock_level[i]
    made = y - x
    if made <= 0:
        print("Insufficient")
    else:
        # stock_leve minus required   
        new_stock_level.append(made)
        print("Product created")
print(new_stock_level, "\nNumber of product created: {}".format(len(new_stock_level)))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. The code that you've provided works, however, I was wondering if there is anyway to track how many products have been made i.e. how many times it went into the else part of the code.

Comment: Yes, of course.  the `i` is how many products are provided. Just add `print(i)` to the `else` or just print(len(stock_level)) after the loop. I have modified my answer to meet your requirement.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I was unclear in my explanation. The products can only be made if all values in the stock_level list is greater than the ones in required. For example, if stock_level = [20, 20, 20, 20] and required = [70, 20, 20, 20], no products should have been made. In the code that you have provided, 3 products were still being made. Thanks!

Comment: I have modified my codes again. See the new code snippet.

Comment: It still returns "Number of product created: 1", even though the 2nd member of the stock_level list is lesser than that of required in the code that you have provided in which case the product created should have been 0

Comment: It returns 1 because only `70` is greater than `20` which will create a new product hence the "Number of products created: 1". This should be the answer except if I'm not understanding your explanation.

Comment: All the values in the stock_level list should be greater than the ones in the required list in order for a product to be created. In your example, for 1 product to be created, it requires [20, 20, 20, 20]. However, the 2nd element in the stock_level list is less than 20. Hence, no products should have been created. Apologies for any poor explanation on my part.